# Doing URL Rewriting and Redirections (.htaccess) with same code working both on WAMP localhost and remote folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

first of all, I'm sorry for this umpteenth topic about this kind of problem.
I've tried to adapt other topics to my problem for months without being able to figure out how to do. That's why I'm writing today, it's really bugging me and as of today, I can only successfully do URL rewriting on remote but always coding in production remote folder isn't reliable solution.

This is what my file tree look like :

[image: file tree of original poster]

Firstly, I'd like to be redirected from the root of this 'template1' project to the root of the 'public' subfolder ; and secondly, I'd like to rewrite URLs so this kind of URL :

`template1/index.php?route=qwertyuiop`

turns into that :

`template1/qwertyuiop`

Both these things I want work but only on my remote folder on Ionos and I had to do weird things. For example for the redirection, I'm directly linking domain to subfolder and for URL rewriting I do :

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.pdf|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]`

Anyways, this works fine on remote folders and when I do PHP header("location:/azertyuiop") it works fine but in localhost it tries to search at the root of WAMPserver and I don't know how to proceed to fix it while keeping same code for both local and remote.

If any of you could help me figure out how to deal with this problem, it would be really appreciated as reading topics and putting whatever I can in my .htaccess doesn't work on localhost.

Comment: "but in localhost it tries to search at the root of WAMPserver" - It doesn't sound as if you've configured a `<VirtualHost>` correctly (if at all?) for your site? How have you defined the site in the server config?

Comment: @MrWhite Never heard of " <VirtualHost> ". What does it do ? Sorry I don't know much Apache commands, only a tiny bit of RewriteRule, RewriteCond, and Redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, sooo thanks @MrWhite for basically telling me about VirtualHost. I never saw about it in any topics so I was searching maybe in the wrong direction.
Everything is working fine, now. So in case in the future someone gets through it, I will explain what I did to make it work in localhost. What I will tell is translated from a website I've found in my native language ( [How to configure VirtualHost (French)](https://www.nicolas-verhoye.com/comment-configurer-virtual-hosts-wamp.html) ).


**STEP 1 : edit Apache's config in Wamp**


In the 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file located in 'C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf' (in my case), I had to add these virtual host lines :

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
    `ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost`
    `DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/projets/projets_persos/tests/template1/public"`
    `ServerName template1.local`
    `ServerAlias template1.local`
    `ErrorLog "logs/template1.local-error.log"`
    `CustomLog "logs/template1.local-access.log" common`
`</VirtualHost>`

Then I had to modify Apache's main config file called 'httpd.conf' located in 'C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/conf/httpd.conf' (in my case) and uncomment the following line :

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` (in my case, it was already uncommented)


After that, the website says to restart Wamp's services before step 2, which I did after step 2 below and it stills work without any trouble. So anyway, I guess it will be same for you, do it now or after step 2.


**STEP 2 : edit Windows' hosts file**


At bottom of the 'hosts' file located in 'C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts' I added the following line at bottom of the file to override the previous rule :


`127.0.0.1 template1.local`


**Aaand, that's all.**


**=-=-=-=-=**


As a proof it's working well, here's a screenshot of my project :

[image: Screenshot of URL rewriting fixed in localhost thanks to VirtualHost]


Here you can see on the picture I exploded my route in an array. I do this for personal purposes, to be able to route according to whatever bit of string I want. If you want to get rid of the 'public' value in the route, just type `$_GET['route'] = str_replace('public/', '', $_GET['route']);` before putting each of its fields in the array. Then, it will look like this :

[image: Screenshot of URL rewriting fixed in localhost thanks to VirtualHost]


Also, of course, I used .htaccess to be able to do URL Rewriting, here's my .htaccess file :


`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.pdf|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]`

It's a bit off topic but in case you'd need to know, the RewriteCond lines allow to type in the true URL of assets that have these extensions and it won't rewrite as they are true URLs.


**=-=-=-=-=**


Anyway, this is the end of my solution, thanks again for helping me and all's well that ends well. The End.